# typo3 image - using only GDLib?

Tags: php, typo3, gdlib

I need some help with TYPO3 images - i have in image configuration both ImageMagick and GDLib enabled. Lately, on my hosting ImageMagic installation is no longer available and now i upload images but are not displayed on website. Is it possible to use only GDLib and what should I change in localconf.php.

Below is what i have now:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['disable_exec_function'] = '0';  
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['gdlib_png'] = '0'; 
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_combine_filename'] = 'composite';   
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_path'] = '/usr/bin/';   
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_version_5'] = 'im6';    
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_no_effects']='1'; //recommended in case using IM5+
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_v5effects']='0'; //recommended in case using IM5+


$TYPO3_CONF_VARS ['GFX'] ['JPG_Quality'] = '65';

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS ['FE'] ['compression level'] = '9';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS ['BE'] ['compression level'] = '5';
```

This change will affect existing images?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 can also use GraphicsMagick but if your hoster disabled ImageMagick then probably you have also no way to use GraphicsMagick.

Anyway you can try to enable GraphicsMagick with:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_version_5'] = 'gm';
```

If that fails then the only solution is to change hoster or install extension "jb_gd_resize". This extension changes TYPO3 to use GDLib.